# how to prevent user to select repetitive options?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

"I have a modal whose purpose is to gather form data and filter a list. Within this modal, I have several select inputs that I want to prevent the user from choosing repetitive options. When the user selects an option and clicks on the 'Add' icon, the option is removed from the available options in the select input. Similarly, when the user clicks on the 'Remove' icon, the previously selected option becomes available for selection again. I have implemented the 'Add' functionality successfully, but I am currently stuck on implementing the 'Remove' functionality."

```
const filterOptions = [
  { id: 1, value: "group", label: "group" },
  { id: 2, value: "id", label: "id" },
  { id: 3, value: "title", label:"title" },
  { id: 4, value: "owners", label: "owners" },
  { id: 5, value: "users", label: "users" },
  { id: 6, value: "responsibles", label: "responsibles" },
  { id: 7, value: "reviewDate", label: "reviewDate" },
  { id: 8, value: "description", label:"description" },
];

const equalOptions = [
  { value: "=", label: "equal" },
  { value: "!=", label: "not-equal" },
  { value: "LIKE", label: "like" },
];

const groupOptions = [
  { value: "1", label: " user1" },
  { value: "2", label: "user 2" },
];

const PropertyFilterListModal: React.FC<Props> = ({ onClose }) => {
  const generateId = () =>
    Math.floor(new Date().getTime() * Math.random() * 1000);

  const defaultItem = () => ({
    id: generateId(),
    title: "",
    impact: "",
  });

  const { control, getValues } = useForm<FieldValues>();


  const [propertyFilters, setPropertyFilters] = useState([defaultItem()]);
  const [updatedOptions, setUpdatedOptions] =
    useState<FilterProps[]>(filterOptions);
  const [selectedVal, setSelectedVal] = useState("");

  const handleAdd = () => {
    setPropertyFilters((prev) => [...prev, defaultItem()]);
    setUpdatedOptions((prev) =>
      prev.filter((option) => option.value !== selectedVal)
    );
  };

  const handleRemove = (item: any) => {
    const updatePropertyFilters = [...propertyFilters];
    const colVal = getValues(`${item.id?.toString()}.filterOptions` as any);
    const removedOption = filterOptions.find(
      (option) => option.value === colVal
    );
    setUpdatedOptions((prev) => [removedOption, ...prev]);
    const ind = updatePropertyFilters.findIndex((q) => q.id === item.id);
    if (ind !== -1) {
      updatePropertyFilters.splice(ind, 1);
      setPropertyFilters(updatePropertyFilters);
    }
  };

  const handleUsedFilter = (val: any) => {
    setSelectedVal(val);
  };


  return (
    <Modal isOpen onClose={onClose} >
      <form className="w-[38rem] h-[24rem]" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <section>
          {propertyFilters.map((item, ind) => (
            <section className="flex items-center justify-between">
              <PropertyFilterItem
                key={item.id}
                index={ind + 1}
                control={control}
                item={item}
                filterOptions={updatedOptions}
                equalOptions={equalOptions}
                groupOptions={groupOptions}
                onFilterChanged={handleUsedFilter}
              />

              {propertyFilters.length === 1 ? null : (
                <div className="mb-3 w-9">
                  <span className="w-1/12 block ">
                    <span
                      className="block cursor-pointer transition text-red-500 hover:text-red-800"
                      onClick={() => handleRemove(item)}
                    >
                      <Remove />
                    </span>
                  </span>
                </div>
              )}
            </section>
          ))}

          <div>
            <span className="w-1/12 ml-2 flex items-center justify-center">
              <span
                className="block cursor-pointer transition text-green-500 hover:text-green-800"
                onClick={handleAdd}
              >
                <Add />
              </span>
            </span>
          </div>
        </section>
        <section className="flex justify-end mt-5 gap-3">
          <Button size="lg" color="danger">
            cancle
          </Button>
          <Button size="lg" color="success">
            view
          </Button>
        </section>
      </form>
    </Modal>
  );
};

export default PropertyFilterListModal;
```

and here is my child component for adding rows:

```
const PropertyFilterItem: React.FC<Props> = ({
  control,
  item,
  filterOptions,
  equalOptions,
  groupOptions,
  onFilterChanged,
}) => {
  const [showInput, setShowInput] = useState(true);
  const [showSelect, setShowSelect] = useState(false);

  const handleChangeEqualOptions = (value: string | number) => {
    console.log(value);
    switch (value) {
      case "LIKE":
        setShowInput(true);
        setShowSelect(false);
        break;
    }
  };

  const handleChangeFilterOptions = (value: string | number) => {
    onFilterChanged(value);
    switch (value) {
      case "owners":
      case "responsibles":
      case "users":
        setShowInput(false);
        setShowSelect(true);
        break;
      default:
        setShowInput(true);
        setShowSelect(false);
        break;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="flex w-full items-center gap-2">
      <SelectController
        formClassName="w-[176px]"
        control={control}
        options={filterOptions}
        name={`${item.id?.toString()}.filterOptions`}
        onChangeValue={handleChangeFilterOptions}
      />
      <SelectController
        formClassName="w-[128px]"
        name={`${item.id?.toString()}.equalOptions`}
        control={control}
        options={equalOptions}
        onChangeValue={handleChangeEqualOptions}
      />
      {showInput && (
        <InputController
          name={`${item.id?.toString()}.input`}
          control={control}
          formClassName="w-[248px]"
        />
      )}
      {showSelect && (
        <SelectController
          formClassName="w-[248px]"
          name={`${item.id?.toString()}.select`}
          control={control}
          options={groupOptions}
          isMulti
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default PropertyFilterItem;
```

"With this implementation, I am experiencing a few bugs related to the 'Remove' button and adding the option back to the select input. If you have any ideas on how to resolve these issues, please let me know. Thank you."

Comment: Can you put this in an online IDE like CodeSandbox or something? It would make it easier for folks to see what is actually happening.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-pond-t6dc4r?file=/src/components/PropertyFilterItem.tsx